# Missing jQuery in a Wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

Using Astra theme, I cannot use jQuery on the frontend. It keeps logging `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at VM105:23`. It is actually supposed that Wordpress is equipped with jQuery, but I cannot figure out why I get that 'undefined' error message in console.

So as to add jQuery, I just write the following code, yet to no effect:

```
    function addjq () {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/in/jq.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjq');
```

I am using this piece inside a widget, and it is not including `jquery` to the frontend. It actually comes up with that `Uncaught ReferenceError`. Is the problem somehow related to my `jquery` file url, or is it a core problem that I need to address. Can you help me out of the problem, and let me know how I can use `jquery` inside a plugin **`widget`**. The following jQuery code throws that console error:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // Some Code Goes Here...
  })
```

I also tried to add a `src` attribute to the script tag, and bring in the jQuery. **`RESULT`**: The error disappeared, yet no jQuery code was run. Even I could not do a simple `console.log()`.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with the jQuery code I had written.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      // Some Code Goes Here...
    })
```

Just take a look at the complete segment:

```
    public function doSomethingSpecific() {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" >
                              
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                      console.log('Hello World!');
                    })

                }

            </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Since the above function was not correctly enqueued, and actually supposedly kept running before jQuery was loaded, I received that `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at VM105:23` error. So what I did to solve the problem was to wait for the page to load fully and then call the code. Therefore I changed that `jQuery` segment shown above to the following and it was good to go. Problem Solved, and definitely there was no need to enqueue `'jQuery'`.

```
    public function webcamcapchur() {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" >
                window.onload = function doLoadThePage(event) {
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                      console.log('Hello World!');
                    })
                }

            </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Knowledge

By default jQuery is **REGISTERED**. It is **ENQUEUED ONLY** on the **admin side**.

To suit everyones needs, the Wordpress core jQuery version isn't the most recent one.

| Script Name | Handle | Needed Dependency | Script version | License |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) | `jquery` | json2 (for AJAX calls) | `1.12.4` | MIT + (MIT OR BSD) |

- Source @ [`wp_enqueue_script()` function CODEX page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)

For most recent Wordpress versions (WP > `3.8`), a jQuery migrate version is in place. Runing the latest jQuery `3.5.1`

| Handle | Path in WordPress |
| --- | --- |
| `jquery-migrate` | /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js (`v1.10.2` as of WP `3.8`) |

If you want to enqueue your own version it's common practice to de-register the core jQuery version on the front end.

```
<?php
if( ! is_admin() ) {
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}; ?>
```

---

### Your error

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/in/jq.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
```

Here you are pretty much asking jQuery to enqueue himself behind himself. You defined a `jquery` handle (which is already use by jQuery core). And you specify `array( 'jquery' ) / ...` that `jquery` shouldn't enqueue before `jquery`.

---

### What could we do?

Well let's say we're going to use our own jQuery to be sure we are using the latest version. We deregister jQuery core using `wp_deregister_script()`, we are going to use a CDN to get our latest version from the [jQuery website](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js). We can put in place a fallback system using `@fopen`. And we can append all necessary attributes like the `integrity` key and the `crossorigin` or the `preload prefetch` attributes to a new script tag, to ensure global performances.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
  if( ! is_admin() ) {

    /**
    * Deregister Wordpress jquery core version
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/
    */
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    /**
    * Register then enqueue jquery_js
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    *
    * Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
    * @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
    *
    * Add rel='preload' <link> and required attributes to jquery_js
    * Filters the HTML link tag of an enqueued style & add required attributes
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/
    */
    $test_jquery_js = @fopen( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'r' );
    if( $test_jquery_js !== false ) {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    } else {
      wp_register_script( 'jquery_js', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array(), '3.5.1', true );
    };
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js' );
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'data_jquery_js', 10, 3 );
    function data_jquery_js( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
      if( $handle === 'jquery_js' ) {
        $integrity = 'sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=';
        $tag = str_replace(
          array(
            "<script",
            "></script>",
          ),
          array(
            "<link rel='preload prefetch' href='" . esc_url( $src ) . "' as='script' integrity='" . $integrity . "' crossorigin='anonymous' />" . PHP_EOL . "<script",
            "integrity='" . $integrity . "' crossorigin='anonymous' async></script>",
          ),
          $tag
        );
      };
      return $tag;
    };

  };
};
```